# Using Command Prompt to merge csv files without copying header row

Tags: csv, command, prompt

I am trying to copy all csv files in a folder into 1 merged file. My command is:

copy *.csv Merged.csv

It works but each file has 1 header row and 1 data row so I get a header row and data row for each file.

How can I skip the header row?
Ideally I would get the header row to appear 1 time at top and then only the second row (data) of the remaining csv files.

Answer (score 0):

Can you handle awk? Test data:

```
$ cat file
head1 head2
1 2
3 4
```

Using the same data more than once:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR||FNR>1' file file file # > finalfile.csv
head1 head2
1 2
3 4
1 2
3 4
1 2
3 4
```